# In angularjs log.error.logs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, logging

Here is the plunker--> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oShq6IhOKYvdU65StRmn?p=preview)

Can someone tell me why $log.error.logs is not working.

I applied debug mode on the js, and on the console I am getting only these objects, $log.error, which is a function. I am getting $logs.error.logs as undefined, while according to the documentation of angularjs, I should be getting an array of error messages when I do $logs.error.logs. Here is the link of the [AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$log)...

Is it because I am not implementing angular-mocks.js in my file?

Also, when I do adding angular-mocks.js, the code doesnt work only.

Here is the plunker after adding ngMocks. [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UgSO0zlPqbxuZRRYSBa1?p=preview)

```
    var app = angular.module('logExample',['ngMock']);    app.controller('LogController', [ '$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$log = $log;
    $scope.warnMsgs="warning msgs";
    $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
    //exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
    //$scope.message = exception.message;
    //console.log($log.warn.logs);
    /*giveWarning();
    var */giveWarning=function(){
        //console.log($log.warn.logs);
        console.log("Inside giveWarning()");
        $scope.warnMsgs=$log.warn.logs;
        console.log($scope.warnMsgs);
    };

} ]);
```

Comment: It's working in the second fiddle or plunker :-P

Comment: Its not :( ya plunker(not fiddle, sry)